# Error importing tensorflow because of wrong architecture

Tags: macos, python-3.4, tensorflow

I am attempting to install [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) on my `Mac ( OSX El Capitan 10.11.2)` following the instructions listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html)

I used pip to install `tensorflow` for `Python3` and it appears that everything installed successfully.

But when I go to test it, I am greeted with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

This error is not listed on the common problems and I couldn't find anything conclusive on my own.

---

Update:
@mrry Alrighty, `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)` is returning `2147483647` so python is running in 32bit mode.

Comment: Can you remove tensorflow (pip uninstall) and try to reinstall? I had a similar issue, but it is gone when I remove and reinstall.

Comment: @SungKim Yes I pip uninstalled both tensorflow and protobuf (listed under common problems) but the same error occurs when I reinstall.

Comment: Did you also install Tensorflow for Python 2.7? If so, try to remove it as well.

Comment: In your Python shell, can you try running `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)` and report what it prints? (It sounds like you have a 32-bit version of Python installed; whereas the TensorFlow PIP packages are built for 64-bit architectures.)

Comment: @mrry thanks. Switching to 64bit did the trick. Post your answer formally so I can give you credit.

Comment: @TaylorRedden how did you switch to 64 bit?